# JsonRequestBehavior equivalent in Json.Net with Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, json.net

Since ASP.NET MVC2, when you try to return a Json result without additional information, you get an error:

> This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request.

You must now set the property `JsonRequestBehavior` to the value `AllowGet`:

```
result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
```

I [read on a post](http://www.ifunky.net/blog/post/AspNet-MVC-2-JsonRequestBehaviorAllowGet.aspx) that this prevents hijacking.

I wanted to know if there is an equivalent with Json.Net to prevent this type of attack.

Here is my code to create the Json result:

```
  protected JsonNetResult JsonNet(object data)
  {
     JsonNetResult result = new JsonNetResult();

     result.Data = data;

     return result;
  }
```

And if you want to know where I found the JsonNetResult, [here is a link](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net.aspx).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need it because in the custom `JsonNetResult` that you have shown there's no such test. So you will never get an exception like the one you would get with the standard `JsonResult` if you invoke the action with GET.

If you wanted you could implement exactly the same property on your custom `JsonNetResult` property.

```
public class JsonNetResult : ActionResult
{
    public JsonNetResult()
    {
        SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet;
    }

    public JsonRequestBehavior JsonRequestBehavior { get; set; }
    ....

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        var httpMethod = context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod;

        if (JsonRequestBehavior == JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet && 
            string.Equals(httpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You can't access this action with GET");
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

and if you wanted to explicitly allow this for a particular action:

```
protected ActionResult JsonNet(object data)
{
    JsonNetResult result = new JsonNetResult();
    result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    result.Data = data;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Darin. It's an honnor for me to receive an answer from one of the most powerful contributor of StackOverflow.